# Xcode not sending new build to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

Recently i wanted to release an update for my app everything worked fine expect my build was not being sent i tried everything and checked everything version number,build number...etc.

After archiving my build and hitting the button sent to App Store (iTunes connect) its finished so fast which was odd to me but finished with a success so i assumed it worked. Checking my iTunes countless hours and times later still nothing.

**Im answering my own question i found the solution**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is basically an answer without a question, the answer was made at the same time as the question.

Comment: thats not not off topic

Comment: just because it doesn't help u doesn't mean it won't help other people i was stuck on this problem for ever.

Comment: Yes, asking a question and immediately answering is allowed. But the site is basically about helping developers with a problem. Also the question and answer are lacking basic information such as the versions of Xcode involved since this Q/A will still be here for many future version of Xcode. Was this a minor point release (ex: 6.3 to 6.4) or a major release (ex: 5.x to 6.x).

Answer (score 1):

We've also faced same issue before few days.You can upload application with Application loader and it will surely work for you.

Answer (score -3):

The problem was i didn't update Xcode which seems stupid of me for not updating but u know stuff happens the point of this is Xcode didn't tell me i needed to update for my build to be visible and sent in general. Everything in the process seemed just fine just as normal but no build.

So i just wanted to let everybody know just in cause anybody else has ran into this problem. or for the future

GOOD LUCK:)

Comment: I recommend [filing a bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com) with Apple. If Xcode can't upload a binary, it should tell you why.